# Adicionar um círculo distante em volta de uma imagem em CSS

Tags: html, css

Preciso fazer um círculo em volta de uma `div` com foto, porém minha imagem não está centralizando no círculo esperado, tendo esse resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer dessa forma:

```css
#avatar {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj7eP.jpg');
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block; 
    border: 2px solid rgb(161,196,66);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<span class="circle">
     <div id="avatar"></div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cara o certo mesmo seria não usar um `span` como *container* para a imagem e sim usar uma `div` que já é um elemento do tipo `block`, pois não faz sentido colocar `display:block` em um `span`

De qq forma com `display:flex` no `span` vc consegue alinhar no centro independente da largura e altura dos elementos usando `justify-content: center;`
`align-items: center;`. Existem outras formas de fazer, com `position:absolute` etc, mas essa eu acho a mais prática...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja código que usei para ter essa imagem acima:

```css
#avatar {
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj7eP.jpg');
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: top center;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle {
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block; 
 border: 2px solid rgb(161,196,66);
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 80px;
 width: 80px;
 display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<span class="circle">
 <div id="avatar"></div>
</span>
```